# Binomial distribution and complementary event

Tags: probability

The probability of a piece is broken is $0.1$.

If I check each piece separately, what's is the probability of at most 5 pieces must be drawn to find 4 that are not broken.

What I thought was: if $X$ is the number of broken pieces, then
$$X\sim Binomial(5,0.1)$$
Then, I want to evaluate
$$P(X=1)=\binom{5}{1}\cdot0.1^1\cdot0.9^4\cong0.32805$$
But the final answer is $0.91854$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that this should be $\Pr(X=1)$?  What about $\Pr(X=0)$?

Comment: @JMoravitz cause since it wants 4 to be not broken among 5, than 1 must be broken.

Comment: "*At most 5 pieces must be drawn to find 4 that are not broken*" to me reads as that we draw pieces one at a time, adding one to our "not-broken-pile" until our not-broken-pile has at least four in it.  It might be the case that we draw four not-broken in a row and stop at four draws.  It might be the case that we draw one broken and four not-broken among the first five.  It might be the case that we draw two broken and four not-broken among the first six, etc...  The question was the probability that we drew five or fewer overall before being allowed to stop

Comment: If we were to go ahead and draw five, regardless of if we were allowed to stop early or not, we see that we succeed at getting our first four not-broken pieces within those first five iff we drew one *or zero* broken pieces within those five.  The correct answer should have been $\Pr(X=1)\color{red}{+\Pr(X=0)}$ which is $\approx 0.32805 + 0.9^5 \approx 0.91854$ as expected.

Comment: @JMoravitz I got it. I have to study more how to interpret these problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you familiar with the negative binomial?

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq 5]=\binom{4-1}{4-1}\cdot0.9^4\cdot0.1^{4-4}+\binom{5-1}{4-1}\cdot0.9^4\cdot0.1^{5-4}= 0.91854$$

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if there are at most $5$ pieces drawn for $4$ pieces that are not broken, then there are

i) **either** $4$ draws - first $4$ pieces are all good pieces (not broken)
ii) **or** $5$ draws - $3$ out of first $4$ pieces are not broken and $5$th drawn piece is not broken.

So the desired probability is

$\displaystyle 0.9^4 + \binom{4}{1} \times 0.1 \times 0.9^3 \times 0.9 = 0.91854$